Simulating left arrow key is not working using Selenium Java on a popup while saving passkey

I am using Selenium webdriver in Cucumber BDD to automate my web UI application.
I have a scenario of automating passkey creation and i am using 1 password browser extension to enable the passkey creation.
on clicking create passkey, 1 password popup appears and all elements underneath it are embedded under shadow root(closed)

So i am using Java robot class key press and actions class keys but tab is working but left arrow is not working which is critical step to save new passkey
Option1
 Robot rb = new Robot();
 
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(2000);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(2000);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(1000);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
Thread.sleep(3000);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
Thread.sleep(3000);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);
Thread.sleep(1000);
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_HOME);

Option2

Actions actRef=new Actions(getDriver());
actRef.sendKeys(Keys.HOME).perform();
actRef.sendKeys(Keys.HOME);
actRef.build();
actRef.perform();
Thread.sleep(5000);
   
Option3
WebElement shadowHost = getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("com-1password-notification"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
WebElement shadowElement = (WebElement) js
        .executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('button:nth-of-type(1)');", shadowHost);
shadowElement.click();
System.out.println("Hello I Did my Part");

Popup to click on new item and save

